# Using filename as parameter on powershell function/script

Tags: powershell-2.0

good afternoon

Recently I've been trying to adapt [this powershell script](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/06/01/use-powershell-to-modify-file-access-time-stamps.aspx) (from "Hey, Scripting Guy! Blog") to modify the file timestamps (CreationTime, LastAccessTime, and LastWriteTime) of a single file instead of the files of a folder. But, I've been having problems on make it work with modifications that I've made.

The original script is as follows:

```
Set-FileTimeStamps function

Function Set-FileTimeStamps
{
    Param (
        [Parameter(mandatory=$true)]
        [string[]]$path,
        [datetime]$date = (Get-Date))
    Get-ChildItem -Path $path |
    ForEach-Object {
        $_.CreationTime = $date
        $_.LastAccessTime = $date
        $_.LastWriteTime = $date
    }
} #end function Set-FileTimeStamps
```

And the modified one is this:

```
Function Set-FileTimeStamps
{
    Param (
        [Parameter(mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$file,
        [datetime]$date = (Get-Date))
    $file.CreationTime = $date
    $file.LastAccessTime = $date
    $file.LastWriteTime = $date
} #end function Set-FileTimeStamps
```

An when I try to run the script it throws me the following error:

```
Property 'CreationTime' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
At C:\Users\Anton\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Set-FileTimeStamps\Set-FileTimeStamps.psm1:7 char:11
+ $file. <<<< CreationTime = $date
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

So, it's not clear to me where I'm failing while modifying the original script, and I would be thankful if someone could point me the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type `[string]` does not have `CreationTime`, `LastAccessTime` and `LastWriteTime`  properties just because is a file name... it's always a `[string]` type.
You need to pass a `[system.io.fileinfo]` type as parameter of your script or cast to this type:

```
Function Set-FileTimeStamps
{
    Param (
        [Parameter(mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$file,
        [datetime]$date = (Get-Date))

        $file = resolve-path $file     
        ([system.io.fileinfo]$file).CreationTime = $date
        ([system.io.fileinfo]$file).LastAccessTime = $date
        ([system.io.fileinfo]$file).LastWriteTime = $date
    } #end function Set-FileTimeStamps
```

in the original script the cmdlet  `Get-ChildItem -Path $path` return a [fileinfo] type that's why it works.